# BOD5 respirometric method

Tags: analytical-chemistry, equipment

I operate in a wastewater treatment plant laboratory and I use respirometric method for BOD5 measurement (hach direct plus). Recently I am obtaining high value for BOD (biological oxygen demand) for example BOD5 581 mg/L when the COD (chemical oxygen demand) of the same sample 895 mg/L. I did multiple assays on another sample and I obtained different values for the same sample using the same initial volume (209 mg/L and 586 mg/L while COD 630 mg/L).
I thought that some sensors are not functioning properly. I want to know if these pressure sensors can be calibrated, anyone can help please??

Comment: You might want to provide more information on what specific sensors you are talking about (make and model).

Comment: @Buck Thorn I did, thank you for notifying

Comment: Just to confirn, you mean this: https://uk.hach.com/other-instruments/bod-direct-plus/family?productCategoryId=51137362617 ?

Comment: A few simple questions just in case: 1) have you read the accompanying manual thoroughly and checked the troubleshooting section?  2) have you followed a standard protocol, if so, what is it? 3) have you checked that your sensor is not too old (past its nominal useful lifetime as provided by the manufacturer)?

Comment: @Buck Thorn, yes it is this one. I read the manual and there is nothing about this problem. All they said about the sensor's maintenance and care is to wipe them with dry cloth and that's what I was doing... I am following the procedure written in the manual. I am using the sensors from about 2 years...

Comment: I am reading the following manual: DOC342.52.90554 . It  would be good to know exactly what sensor you're using (part number etc). This one (https://www.hach.com/hq40d-portable-biochemical-oxygen-demand-bod-meter-laboratory-kit-with-luminescent-do-sensor-and-bod-bottles-1-m-cable/product?id=7640513827) for instance keeps track of how long you've used it and "remaining life".

Comment: On page 7 of the manual there are some potentially useful warnings (I don't know how experienced you are with the device).

Comment: @Buck Thorn yes the manual you are reading is the true one. I think I am experienced with the device because I am using it from about 2 years in 2 different laboratories and I am facing this problem only with one of them. I took a sample to the second lab and used the second equipment and obtained better results. I am just asking for someone who used this equipment before to see if there is any calibration method for the sensors. Anyway thank you so much for your help

Comment: That's fine, it's important to know as much as possible about the problem in question to give a proper answer. Every device should be calibrated, but to be honest that doesn't sound like the problem. The problem, as I gather from what you wrote originally, is that you observe enormous variability between measurements. That is a precision problem, not accuracy. Calibrations of the sort you might carry out with such a probe usually aim to improve accuracy.

Comment: In any event, if there is a standard method to calibrate the device it would be specified in the manual or the literature, and I would not recommend using a third parties recommendations, unless you don't worry about SOPs, GLP etc. In addition you have not specified which exact probe you are using, only the readout device.

Comment: @Buck Thorn, many thanks for your help, I contacted the supplier and have been told that the sensors can't be calibrated maybe the problem is in the direct plus apparatus. Anyway I will send the equipment to the supplier and they will work to fix it. Thank you for your help.